# Is there any way to avoid creating reference to original file when pasting formula to different file? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code which search for cells formatted in certain way, copy them and paste to another file (both files are just different versions of same form). Copied cells contain reference to other sources as well as to cells in same file, example:

```
= '[DataSource]Sheet'!F15 - C15
```

But after copy and paste to other file it looks like that, with reference to source/original file:

```
= '[DataSource]Sheet'!F15 - '[OriginalFile]Sheet'!C15
```

Is there any way to copy formula with vba code from one file to another, without creating reference to original file? It should just looks like original one.

Below is part of my code responsible for copy/paste part:

```
    For Each A In crg.Areas
        ws2.Range(A.Address).Copy
        A.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next A
```

I just don't want to adjust pasted formulas manually, deleting "[OriginalFile]Sheet" part everytime. Is there any way to avoid creating reference to original file in parts with reference to cell in formula?

Comment: You could paste as values or you can use replacement in formulas text and replace all instances of `[OriginalFile]Sheet` with whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

Try copy and pasting the formula via the formula bar (F2) - then it won't make the adjustments.

VBA to copy formulas to a different range:

```
Public Sub copyFormula(cSource As Range, cTarget As Range)
With cSource
    cTarget.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Formula = .Formula
End With
End Sub
```

If you use new formulas like `XLOOKUP` you might have to use `.Formula2`

You might call it like this

```
For Each A In crg.Areas
   copyFormula ws2.Range(A.Address), a
Next A
```